# Subset Text Similarity Score - How to detect a piece of small text that is very similar to subset of a much bigger text

Tags: nlp, similarity

There are many ways to detect similarity between 2 texts like Jaccard Index, TFIDF cosine similarity or sentence embedding. However all of them are refering to use case of 2 texts which are fully to be compared.

Here, I don't know how to call it but I add Subset Text Similarity Score, is to detect/calculate a score to see whether a small text is an extract from a bigger text.

For example, there is a big text (from a news)

```
Google Stadia, the company's cloud gaming service, will shut down on January 18 after the game failed to gain the traction with users the company had hoped for.

The cloud gaming service debuted through a closed beta in October 2018 and publicly launched in November 2019.

In spite of the fact that users are about to lose access to all of their titles and save on Stadia, many publishers share ways to keep playing their games on other platforms, reports The Verge.

Moreover, Google is also refunding all Stadia hardware purchased through the Google Store as well as all the games and add-on content purchased from the Stadia store.
```

the objective of the subset text similarity is to detect whether this small text is a subset (extract) from the bigger text above. The small text can have sentences not in the same order as the bigger text to be compared.

Example small text

```
On Stadia, users are will lose access to all of their titles and saves. all Stadia hardware purchased through the Google Store will be refunded.
```

For a small text above, the subset similarity score should be very high.

Is there some package or NLP method that can do this?